# Passing output of tree through pipeline (BASH)

Tags: bash, tree, pipe

Sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything.

I have an issue with a (example) script that needs to do 2 things:
echo the output of the tree command, and echo the same again, but this time passing the output through a pipe to another script.

The first part works fine, I get the expected tree of of directories and files, output on the terminal.

However when passing the output through the pipe, all I get on the other side is the first line. Why is this?
I have tried assigning the output to a temporary file and then using cat on this before passing through, but with no success.

Thanks

```
example_script:

tree Folder          
tree Folder > test.pipe  


...

#The other script reads from the pipe like so:

read thisthing < test.pipe
echo $thisthing  #I have also tried cat $thisthing
```

Comment: The read builtin only consumes a single line. Use `mapfile` to read the entire thing into a single variable.

Comment: `read` reads just one line at a time by default. You're probably looking for `thisthing=$(<test.pipe)`

Comment: @oguzismail that worked! thanks

Comment: Use quotes: `echo "$thisthing"` after applying improvement of @oguzismail

Comment: is there any way I can accept a comment as an answer?